# phpMyAdmin removes the primary key for MySQL table

Tags: mysql, wamp, phpmyadmin

My problem is this:
I create a table in WAMP Server's phpMyAdmin,
I always make the first column as

```
name: id
type: int
index: primary
auto_increment: true
```

then I add other columns , mostly harmless `int`'s or `varchar`'s. And sometimes `timestamp`'s with `DEFAULT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I save the table with no problems.

Then when I'm starting to use this table in my php scripts, I add a value without stating a value for id, since it is `auto_increment`, so like this:

```
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO mytable(harmless_int, harmless_varchar) VALUES ('42','marvin');");
```

and when I go to check my table in phpMyAdmin, I see that the value for `id` is 0.
Further, I click "Structure", then "Change" for column `id`, and I see that it does not have `auto_increment` property anymore. So I `DROP` the table, create it the exact same way again, then it works.

This happened me a lot, I always have to create the same table twice. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is down to a table copy that you've done.

I can only think that you might have done something like this in the past:

`CREATE TABLE [new_table] SELECT * FROM [old_table]`

It seems that although it preserves the column names and data, it does not preserve the structure and keys.

How do I know? - I just found out the hard way.